# PowerShell GetHelp only returning file name of script.ps1 file

Tags: powershell, markdown

I must be missing something simple here.

I have implemented some help comments in one of my functions in my ps1 file :

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Adds a file name extension to a supplied name.

.DESCRIPTION
Adds a file name extension to a supplied name.
Takes any strings for the file name or extension.

.PARAMETER Name
Specifies the file name.

.PARAMETER Extension
Specifies the extension. "Txt" is the default.

.INPUTS
None. You cannot pipe objects to Add-Extension.

.OUTPUTS
System.String. Add-Extension returns a string with the extension or file name.

.EXAMPLE
C:\PS> extension -name "File"
File.txt   

#>
```

When I run the Get-Help "Function Name" directly after the function and run the ps1 script via powershell window, I get the correct response.

Now, I am using the code from here : http://ben.neise.co.uk/scriptdocumentationinmarkdown/

This is suppose to generate some Markdown documentation from the help comments within my script files. When running it I get the error :

```
GenerateScriptDocumentationInMarkdown : Inline help not found for script C:\****\testScript.ps1
```

(GenerateScriptDocumentationInMarkdown being the function name).

The line it errors is the line where I call the function with some filepaths :

```
GenerateScriptDocumentationInMarkdown -SourceScriptFolder "C:\****\testScripts"  -DocumentationOutputFolder "C:\****\GeneratingMarkdownFileTest" -DocumentationIndexPath "C:\****\GeneratingMarkdownFileTest\scripts_Ps1.markdown"
```

What does the 'inline help not found for script' error mean ?

EDIT

Here is where it fails in the script :

```
 $help = Get-Help $script.FullName -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue"       
        if ($help.getType().Name -eq "String"){
            # If there's no inline help in the script then Get-Help returns a string
            Write-Error -Message "Inline help not found for script $($script.FullName)"
        } else {
```

Notice the condition checking if the .Name is of type string. Looks to me the Get-Help on my script is not returning what it is suppose to.

I would expect the `'get-help {pathtofile.ps1}'` would return all the comments in the script file, but all it returns is the scripts name ?

Comment: Sorry @BaconBits i forgot to add where it fails. I have added a new comment. Looks like the get-help is not returning what is expected and only returning the script files name. Any ideas ?

Comment: Wait, you implemented help in *one of the functions* in a file?  The help you're trying to pull is not inline help for a scriptlet?  `Get-Help` only returns help for the top level item.  You'd have to load the function definition and then run `Get-Help {function name}`, and the script you're using isn't built for that.

Comment: @BaconBits thanks for the help, managed to solve. See answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out thanks to @Bacon Bits.

As the comments were in the functions, I was misinterpreting what the generate function does. What I had to do was loop through the functions within the script file and then run the logic on the functions rather than the whole file.

So to get the functions in only this file :

```
 $currentFunctions = Get-ChildItem function:
        # dot source your script to load it to the current runspace
        . $script.FullName
        $scriptFunctions = Get-ChildItem function: | Where-Object { $currentFunctions -notcontains $_ }

        $scriptFunctions | ForEach-Object {
              & $_.ScriptBlock
        }
```

Then loop through and run the logic like so :

```
$scriptFunctions | ForEach-Object {

        $fullName = $_.Name
        $help = Get-Help $fullName -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue" 
.
.
.
```